# Prevent reflow / repaint once the component is rendered ngFor - Angular 8

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have ngFor loop in one of my angular component. there are 8 items (objects) in total. The object looks something like below:

```
{
    id: 3,
    name:'abcdef',
    img_one_src:'assets/img/default.svg',
    img_two_src:'assets/img/hover.svg',
    img_three_src:'assets/img/selected.svg',
    form_control_name: 'abcdef',
    inactive: false,
    hover: true,
    active: true
}
```

Inshort, I am populating form fields dynamically and also the (default, hover, selected) states of a radio buttons.

The issue is when I scroll fast or really fast, I see white blank page because of the repaint that takes place.

I have 3 functions:

```
mouseEnter(item_id : number, type: string) {
   //I have forloop here 
}

mouseLeave(item_id : number, type: string) {
   //I have forloop here 
}

click(item_id : number, type: string) {
   //I have forloop here 
}
```

How to prevent repaint once the component is loaded? I want to avoid repaint when the page is scrolled and ngFor is brought again to the view.

I am not sure if its the loop, or is it images or is it to do with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

By default Angular uses the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` change detection strategy.
The default strategy doesn’t assume anything about the application, therefore every time something changes in our application, as a result of various user events, timers, XHR, promises, etc., a change detection will run on all components.

To solve this issue, you can change detection strategy to use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. This tells Angular that the component only depends on its `@Input()`.

So it will run change detection only when `@Input()` changed.